# What is the meaning/ usage of か?

Tags: grammar, particle-か

I'm a bit confused about the usage of か. I was taught that it means "or" or "whether", so why is this sentence (どの車にするか迷っています) translated as "I was undecided which car to choose."? What is the purpose of か in this sentence and why doesn’t it translate to "whether"? I mean you can’t say "I was undecided about whether which car to choose",right?

Comment: Do you mean 迷っていました?

Comment: Yes! I accidentally typed the wrong Kanji

Answer (score 5):

You can see this か as a means to turn a verb phrase into a noun phrase. For example, the verb phrase 彼が来る can’t be used as it is as an object of a verb. You need to turn it into a noun phrase and that’s where か comes in.

> 彼が来る**か**（が／は）わかりません。

The particle you would expect to go with the verb, in this case either が or は, can be and often is omitted.

This function of か is indeed very similar to one of the functions of “whether” in English.

> I don’t know **whether** he will come.

You can optionally add かどうか corresponding to “or not” in English.

> 彼が来る**かどうか**わかりません。
> I don’t know **whether** he will come **or not**.

In English, interrogatives like “what,” “where,” “who,” “when,” etc. play similar roles to this “whether.”

> I don’t know **when** he will come.

In Japanese, you still need か at the end as a nominalizer.

> 彼が**いつ**来る**か**わかりません。

In this case, you can’t add かどうか just like you can’t say “when he will come or not.”

Your sentence follows this pattern with the interrogative being どの.

> **どの**車にする**か**迷っていました。
> I was undecided **which** car I should choose.

(I assumed 待っていました was a typo for 迷っていました.)

Comment: Yes it was indeed a typo. Thank you so much for explaining!